# Is there a more graceful way of listing vncserver sessions than just getting the list of running PIDs?

Tags: linux, vnc, vncserver

How do you list your `vncserver` sessions?

**[This article](http://cphg.virginia.edu/mackey/2010/07/19/managing-your-vnc-sessions/)** says to do this:

```
$ cat ~/.vnc/*.pid
5910
6790
16589
21891
... and many more
```

Using this method, I could write a script to check each pid, but there has got to be something better.

Is there a better way?  I'd like to see something like:

```
$ vncserver -l
Session  User  Started     Status    Blah
1        jess  3/24 19:00  Active    ?
2        jess  3/21 14:00  Suspended ?
```

EDIT: For example. I have six sessions running, but I can only use one of them. All six show up as running processes.  It would also be nice to see a list for other users too; I just found a server with 95 VNC sessions.  I have no idea which ones are active.

Comment: Have you tried `vncserver -list`?

Comment: I don't see a `-list` option in the man page.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on tightvncserver 1.3.9-6.4ubuntu1, but works on CentOS 7 (I'm guessing I have `tigervnc-1.3.1-9.el7.x86_64.rpm`).

Comment: You could post a suggestion to the VNC project ! If you don't, I will .... eventually ;-)

Comment: @MikeW did that ever happen?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik It works on tigervnc but not on tightvnc

Answer (score 22):

I always use `ps -ef | grep vnc`, then pick out the parts I need from that.

Comment: I have 6 sessions listed.  The only session I can get to is `:6`.  How would I know which sessions are active/still working?

Answer (score 2):

```
ps -ef | grep `whoami` | grep vnc
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Could you please [edit] your answer to give an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.